# Select a range with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an issue trying to maximize the performance of our listview that has pages.

I want the entity framework to do a select statement, but only return a range of the result (range = the items of one page of the listview).

I have searched google but didn't find any results on this. I only found that I can do a .ToList().GetRange(start index, end index), but then all items would be loaded in memory, and that is what I would like to avoid...

Can someone tell me if this can be done? (I don't want to use a stored procedure or view or something like that because our listview has to be reusable...)

Thanks!

Comment: Skip(50).Take(10) on an ordered query will give you 10 items starting from 50th.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use `.Take(x).ToList()`

edit: sorry, try `.Skip(startPosition).Take(numberOfItems).ToList()`

Comment: I think naming `startPosition` is a bit confusing since it's not the start but just before the start. It may be named as `skipRows`.

Comment: @ninbit this is an old answer! It should be the zero-indexed position, i.e. `Skip(1).Take(1)` will skip the item at index=0, and return the item at index=1. But yes, `skipRows` fits better with the `Skip` method.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are not using lazy loading be sure to use Query() before Load() when applying filters to avoid loading the whole collection before applying filters :

```
context.Entry(blog) 
    .Collection(b => b.Posts) 
    .Query() 
    .Skip(startPosition)
    .Take(numberOfItems)
    .Load()
    .ToList();
```

When using the Query method it is usually best to turn off lazy loading for the navigation property. This is because otherwise the entire collection may get loaded automatically by the lazy loading 
mechanism either before or after the filtered query has been executed.

For more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx